# При попытке вставить PDFView с гитхаба, вылетает приложение

Tags: java, android, github

Если вставлять на EmptyActivity, где все пусто, то все работает. А если создаю другой-второй активити и туда вставляю этот PdfView, вылетает приложение. Код думаю незачем, все дефолт.

Comment: И `EmptyActivity` - довольно "дефолтная" активность... Возможно, вы не добавили вторую активность в файл манифеста. [Это делается так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20871106)

Comment: На будущее, когда вылетает и хочешь узнать почему, нужно показать информацию из лога, хотя бы...